# why setState only updates on mutating original state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface list {
name: string,
id: number,
marks: number
}
```

component state :

```
{
listOfStudents: list[],
}
```

now on some event, where marks is modified for a student with given name and following handler function, the following doesn't work

```
currentList = this.state.listOfStudents;
//find the list object with the given name
listToModify = currentList.map(item, ....=> item.name === event.name);
// update its marks
listToModify.marks = event.marks;
//set new state
this.setState({listOfStudents: currentList});
```

But the following works:

```
//get a copy of the object
currentList = [...this.state.listOfStudents];
//find the list object with the given name
listToModify = currentList.map(item, ....=> item.name === event.name);
// update its marks
listToModify.marks = event.marks;
//set new state
this.setState({listOfStudents: currentList});
```

I didn't have to add new data but modify an existing one, why is mutation required in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a given state that is an object or array, react uses only its reference to compare and decide if it will update state, it doesn't do deep comparision between objects values.

the first case you are passing the same reference, therefore there is no update state. actually, if you modify the array at first example, that's actually mutating state directly.

second case you are cloning into a new fresh array, which holds a different reference. since the reference is different from previous array, react now update its state. that's actually the right approach to update state when dealing with arrays/objects.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense, so does it always have to be a deep copy, say I had array of arrays within, do I have to deep copy the last array or top level copying is enough?

Comment: Yes, when you have deep nested objects you would need to do a deep clone. You can use some libs like lodash that implements deep clone to help you out, since it's not native in javascript.